# SOAP WCF Wrapped Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have following WCF Service

```
[ContractType(ContractKnownType.CORE)]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = WcfConstants.WcfNamespace), ServiceBehavior(Namespace = WcfConstants.WcfNamespace)]
[HostAsWebService]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public class DeliveryWebService : IFactoryService
{
    [OperationContract, Sessional]
    public string InboundDelivery(MT_InboundDelivery MT_InboundDelivery)
    {
        var error = "";
        try
        {
            ... some code
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I do a request with following SOAP Message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.MEScontrol.net/WebServices">
  <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
         <web:MT_InboundDelivery>
             <web:HeaderDetails/>
         </web:MT_InboundDelivery>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I add a "InboundDelivery" node to the message it works.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.MEScontrol.net/WebServices">
  <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
       <web:InboundDelivery>
           <web:MT_InboundDelivery>
             <web:HeaderDetails/>
           </web:MT_InboundDelivery>
         <web:InboundDelivery>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However I cannot change the message since this is send by a third-party application. I tried adding properties as [MessageContract(IsWrapped=true)] to my service without any success. I'm very new to SOAP so any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageContarct could control the structure of soap message.

Below is my test code. But if you want to use messageContract, the return type should also be of type MT_InboundDelivery

```
public class DeliveryWebService : IFactoryService
{
    public MT_InboundDelivery InboundDelivery(MT_InboundDelivery MT_InboundDelivery)
    {

        return MT_InboundDelivery;
    }
}
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.MEScontrol.net/WebServices")]

public interface IFactoryService
{
    [OperationContract]
    MT_InboundDelivery InboundDelivery(MT_InboundDelivery MT_InboundDelivery);
}


[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public class MT_InboundDelivery
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string HeaderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the fiddle result.
[image]

If you  don't want to use messageContract and couldn't control the client side.
I think you should change the signature of your method.
For example ,

```
  string MT_InboundDelivery(string HeaderDetails);
```